# What the equivalent to LocalPrintServer and PrintQueue that can be used in WinUI

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3, winui

I'm trying to migrate a WPF application to WinUI 3.

Currently I have the problem that the classes `LocalPrintServer` and `PrintQueue` are missing in WinUI 3, whereas `PrintDocument` is available in the `System.Drawing.Printing` namespace.

What else can be used to enumerate all printers and select the default printer?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In winui3, you could try to use [Print Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/printhelper) to simplify document printing.

And according to the [link](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4419) that Hans Passant provided: the `PrintDocument API` hasn't been updated for WinUI3 yet, and it's an accident that the API is showing up right now.

You could also refer to the link:https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7234

Here is a [Print Sample in WinUI3](https://github.com/marb2000/PrintSample)